# How to find the number of unqiue words in a string in vba?

Tags: vba, string

I'm pretty new to VBA. So I have a string with a bunch of random words in it like this:

"foo Foo FOO Bar FoO Faz FAZ"

How do I find the number of unique words in the string? In the above example, it would be simply 3, as there's only foo, bar, and faz. I have some code here but it outputs the wrong value, I'm not sure if I should be adding it to an array or some sort of database instead and then iterate through the database to check for duplicates.

```
Function UniqueWordCount(TextString As String) As Integer

TextString = LCase(TextString)
Dim Result() As String
Dim Count As Integer
Result = Split(TextString, " ")
Count = UBound(Result()) + 1
Dim k As Integer
Dim repeat As Integer
repeat = 0

For i = LBound(Result) To UBound(Result)
For k = 0 To i
If Result(i) = Result(k) Then
repeat = repeat + 1
End If
Next k
Next i


If repeat > 1 Then
repeat = repeat - 1
End If



repeat = repeat - i

UniqueWordCount = Count - repeat

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scripting.Dictionary` (add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime):

```
Sub foo()
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim s As String
    s = "foo Foo FOO Bar FoO Faz FAZ"
    
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Split(s)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        If Not d.Exists(UCase$(x(i))) Then
            d.Add UCase$(x(i)), "whatever"
        End If
    Next
    
    Debug.Print d.Count ' returns 3
End Sub
```

Or even simpler:

```
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    d(UCase$(x(i))) = "whatever"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

### Count Unique Words in a Sentence

- Be careful with this simple Regex pattern, it may not work as expected.
- Uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines to get a better feel of what is happening.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueWordsCountTEST()
    Dim Sentence As String
    Sentence = "I am using this Regex to get rid off the punctuation,?!:;-. " _
        & "I am using a dictionary to get rid off duplicates, and the " _
        & "dictionary's CompareMode for 'word' to be the same as 'WORD'."
    ' 12 Dupes: I,am,using,to,get,rid,off,the,dictionary,to,the,WORD
    Debug.Print "Unique Words Count = " & UniqueWordsCount(Sentence)
End Sub

Function UniqueWordsCount( _
    ByVal Sentence As String) _
As Long
    
    Dim Matches As Variant
    
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\w+"
        Set Matches = .Execute(Sentence)
        'Debug.Print "All Words Count = " & Matches.Count
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Match As Variant
        For Each Match In Matches
            .Item(Match.Value) = Empty
            'Debug.Print "All Words: " & Match.Value
        Next Match
        UniqueWordsCount = .Count
        'Debug.Print "Unique Words:" & vbLf & Join(.Keys, vbLf)
    End With

End Function
```